# Ubuntu 22.04.4 media sharing not showing videos

Tags: 22.04, file-sharing, shared-folders, media, mediaserver

Ubuntu version is 22.04.4

I enabled sharing via Settings -> Sharing -> Media Sharing

There are images and videos inside the same folder, all images and videos have the same access rights

When I try to access shared data from my TV or Android phone, I can see all the shared folders and images, but I can't see any video files, none of AVI, MP4, MKV